# How to find orthogonal vector sets

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

Assume a vector expressed as
    $$v=\left[e^{j\theta_1},e^{j\theta_2},e^{j\theta_3}\right]^T$$
$\theta_k, k=1..3$ can change. I want to find a set of vectors  $\{v_1,v_2,...v_N\}$, so that $v_i^Hv_j=0$, if $i\neq j$. $H$ represent  conjugate transpose.

The questions are:

- How to find the vectors?
- What is the maximum number of $N$? 3 for the vector defined above?
- If I change the length of vector $v$ from 3 to $L$, is there a relation between $L$ and $N$?

Comment: Non-zero orthogonal vectors must be linearly independent so you cannot find more than $N$ orthogonal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^N$.

Comment: Thank you, Theo. The answer is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, as Theo pointed out, $N \leq 3$. However, as you're requiring that vectors be of the form $v = [z_1, z_2, z_3]$ with $|z_1| = |z_2| = |z_3| = 1$, it would theoretically be possible that $N < 3$.

That is not the case. Take $v_1 = [1,1,1], v_2 = [1,e^{2i\pi/3},e^{4i\pi/3}], v_3 = [1, e^{4i\pi/3},e^{2i\pi/3}]$. Therefore $N = 3$.

Now if you take the above solution and multiply any vector by a complex number of norm 1, you have a solution. Also, swapping the $i$-th and $j$-th coordinates ($1 \leq i < j \leq 3$) in every vector of the solution gives a solution as well.

Hope this clears things up.

EDIT: Let us now generalize for $n$ coordinates. In fact, an analogous solution can be found in a straightforward manner:

Let $\omega = e^{2\pi i/n}$. Notice that $1 + \omega + \omega^2 + \ldots + \omega^{n-1} = 0 = 1 + \omega^2 + \omega^4 + \ldots + \omega^{2(n-1)} = \ldots = 1 + \omega^{n-1} + \ldots + \omega^{(n-1)^2}$. In other words, $$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\omega^{kj} = 0 \text{ for } k = 1,2,\ldots,n-1$$

Using this, if we take $v_k = [1,\omega^k,\omega^{2k},\ldots,\omega^{(n-1)k}]$ for $0 \leq k < n$, the $n$ vectors $v_0,v_1,\ldots,v_{n-1}$ are a solution to the problem.

Comment: Hi Pedro. Thanks a lot for the answer. It is exactly the answer I need. Another question is how to extend it to arbitrary vector length or to find a general formula for generating such an vector set.

Comment: I've edited the answer to address your comment.